# delete function Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been learning laravel 5.2 recently, and i've made a delete function which should delete records from my database but instead of deleteing the records it's adding a blank row into my database

This is the Route im using:

```
Route::resource('producten', 'ProductenController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'destroy', 'edit', 'update', 'create']]);
```

This is the controller function i use for it

```
 public function destroy(request $request , product $product)
{
    $product->delete();

    return redirect(Route('producten.index'));
}
```

This is the form i've made for it.

```
 {{ Form::Open(['Route' => 'producten.destroy', $product], ['method' => 'delete']) }}
                 {{ Form::Submit('delete')}}
              {{ Form::close() }}
```

when i viewed the source-code it said it was using a POST method instead of a delete method, and also when i add($product) i got a blank page, also i found out that when i hit the submit button it goes to the store method i've made and i dont know why,

if u need more information just let me know and i'll add it in the question

Comment: First of all, are you importing the classes as lower case (`request` instead of `Request`) ?  Secondly, how do you expect to pass the model as the second argument to destroy()?  Normally that would be an `$id` then you use `$product = product::find($id)` in the method.

Comment: Devon: you can use Model binding and then you have model object as a argument.

Answer (score 0):

route and method should be in the same array, not in two differents arrays.

```
{{ Form::Open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['producten.destroy', $product]]) }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ Form::Submit('delete')}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: You can use object in route, when using Model Binding

Comment: Ok, if so, nevermind of this, but you still have to use an unique array for passing method and route when declaring Form::Open.  
@MarekSkiba I updated my anwser removing the part relative to model binding. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something wrong  with form. Can you try with this:

```
<form action="{{ route('producten.destroy', ['product' => $product->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <button type="submit">Remove</button>
</form>
```